# Is the MacBook Sudden Motion Sensor logged?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

My MacBook Pro (Unibody 2009) took a fall today and I wonder whether the Sudden Motion Sensor thingy activated to protect the hard drive.

Is this information available in a log anywhere?

Comment: Does your laptop still work? If so, then it worked :P HDDs aren't the most resilient of things, a good fall can easily knacker one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any way to check whether the Sudden Motion Sensor was engaged short of taking it to the Genius Bar and paying them to look at it. Like Phoshi said, if it boots and you didn't lose any data, I wouldn't be too worried as to whether the sensor engaged or not. Just be happy your information is safe :).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty doubtful. Logging from kernel space is not successful often enough to be touted as a feature of any commercial product.